# What is the query to join 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm struggling in joining table.

```
SELECT ordersId, usersName, productName, price, quantity,total
FROM orders o, users u, products p, orderdetail od
WHERE ....
```

the tables are
users table:

```
usersId(pk)|usersName|....
```

products table:

```
productId(pk)|productName|price|...
```

orders table:

```
ordersId(pk)|date|usersId(fk)
```

orderdetails table:

```
ordersId(fk)|productId(fk)|price|quantity|total
```

the output should be
new table:

```
ordersId|usersName|productName|price|quantity|total
```

but the question is... is the output possible to do or not? Because I keep on getting errors if no error no output. Please Help

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful

Answer (score 1):

You need to find common columns among tables, which is how you'll be able to join the data together. The table which contains the majority of the data you want will derive from OrderDetails, so start there and build one join at a time.

```
SELECT OD.OrdersID, U.UsersName, P.ProductName, OD.Price, OD.Quantity, OD.Total
FROM OrderDetails OD 
JOIN Orders O ON O.OrdersID = OD.OrdersID
JOIN Products P ON P. ProductID = OD.ProductID
JOIN Users U ON U.UsersID = O.UsersID
```

Here is a sample of the working code:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9565d9712e7d86b56ddf1656d3b3b914

Please format your question better next time, following the Stack Overflow guidelines for creating tables within questions/answers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.